# filter api data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a class component that fetches data from a single api and stores in different arrays for different categories. I want to implement a search box such that it can update the results dynamically as the users enter in the search box. This is what my component looks like

```
const urls = [
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_FOOD,
];
Promise.all(
  urls.map((url) =>
    fetch(url)
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
                )
).then((data) => {
  const d_Appetizers = data[0][0].foods;
  const d_Breads = data[0][1].foods;
  const d_ChefSpecial = data[0][2].foods;
  const d_ItemsMenu = data[0][7].foods;
  const d_MealofDay = data[0][3].foods;
  const d_NonVeg = data[0][4].foods;
  const d_PastaandSan = data[0][8].foods;
  const d_RiceKitchen = data[0][9].foods;
  const d_Salads = data[0][10].foods;
  const d_SweetCorner = data[0][11].foods;
  const d_TandooriSpecial = data[0][6].foods;
  const d_veg = data[0][5].foods;
  this.setState({
    Appetizers: d_Appetizers,
    Breads: d_Breads,
    ChefSpecial: d_ChefSpecial,
    ItemsMenu: d_ItemsMenu,
    MealofDay: d_MealofDay,
    NonVeg: d_NonVeg,
    PastaandSan: d_PastaandSan,
    RiceKitchen: d_RiceKitchen,
    Salads: d_Salads,
    SweetCorner: d_SweetCorner,
    TandooriSpecial: d_TandooriSpecial,
    veg: d_veg,
  });
});
```

and the render functions is here

```
<ul className="ulmenu">
        <h2>Appetizers</h2>
        {this.state.Appetizers.map((items) => {
          return <Item items={items} key={items.id}/>;
        })}
        <hr />
        <h2>Breads</h2>
        {this.state.Breads.map((items, index) => {
          return <Item items={items} key={index} />;
        })}
        <hr />
        <h2>Starters</h2>
        {this.state.ItemsMenu.map((items, index) => {
          return <Item items={items} key={index} />;
        })}
```

etc etc...

now  how do I implement a proper search here? thanks for reading!

Comment: Could you please add what exactly you are searching here. Are you searching for different food items?

Comment: Yes, I want the filtered data to replace whatever data the api loads

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a search input box to search for all foods? assuming that the food fields are the same, try this:

```js
class Food extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ keyword: evt.target.value })
  }

  filterFoods = (foods = []) => {
    const { keyword } = this.state

    if (!keyword || keytword === '') {
      return foods
    }

    return foods.filter(food => food.name === keyword)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="search..."
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        />
        <ul className="ulmenu">
          <h2>Appetizers</h2>
          {this.filterFoods(this.state.Appetizers).map((items) => {
            return <Item items={items} key={items.id}/>;
          })}
          <hr />
          <h2>Breads</h2>
          {this.filterFoods(this.state.Breads).map((items, index) => {
            return <Item items={items} key={index} />;
          })}
          <hr />
          <h2>Starters</h2>
          {this.filterFoods(this.state.ItemsMenu).map((items, index) => {
            return <Item items={items} key={index} />;
          })}
        </ul>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have an error saying handlechange and filterFoods is not defined, am i supposed to define those in the initial state?

Comment: can you post your code? this is what I wrote according to your goals. I haven't actually tested it but the logic is just like this.